# Alfresco Share Folder Based Permission

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have the following scenario: in Alfresco Share, I need to set up different Folder-Access permissions. For instance, User A may have "contributor" access to Folder 1, but only "Consumer" access to Folder 2, whereas User B needs to have "contributor" access to both.
How is this scenario implementable within the Alfresco Roles/Groups model?
I know that we can set up Folder-level permissions in Share, but only based on Roles...

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that if you use Manage Permissions while looking at the Site, you will only see the Site roles. However if you click the "Repository" link at the top of the page and then navigate to your site through the "Sites" folder, you'll be able to manage the permissions and set individual users and groups to have exactly the role you want them to have.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use **Manage Permission** of **Folder Actions** in **Folder Details page** for individual folders?
In there, you can set any permission of individual user to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff and Swemon are both right, this works.

I've also notice that you'll need to clear/un-check "Inherit Permission" in order to do per-user permissions.  It is not right away obvious that you need to do this - I puzzled over the interface for a second or three.  You will find that button on Folder Actions > Folder Details > Manage Permissions.